# Prevent Insert and Update record having OLD date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to prevent 3 things

1. Prevent updating records if the existing date is older than 2022-01-01
2. Prevent updating record if the new date is older than 2022-01-01
3. Prevent insert if the date is less than 2022-01-01.

Basically, it should not allow insert or update the record if date is less than 2022-01-01.

I tried with a trigger with a cursor. I have to use cursor since it should work on batch.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerDate
ON tb
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IVDate Date;

    DECLARE my_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
         SELECT InvoiceDate 
         FROM INSERTED; 

    OPEN my_Cursor; 
     
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_Cursor INTO @IVDate;
        
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM my_Cursor INTO @IVDate;

        IF @IVDate < '2022-01-01'
           ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    CLOSE my_Cursor; 
    DEALLOCATE my_Cursor;
END
```

But the issue arises with order of insert statement.

For example - the following statement **works well**.

```
insert into tb values (1, '2022-05-02','A');
insert into tb values (2, '2021-08-06','B');
```

But the following does not work:

```
insert into tb values (2, '2021-08-06','B');
insert into tb values (1, '2022-05-02','A');   -- This record is correct but still it won't insert
```

Same thing happens with UPDATE statement having where condition with OR

For quick understanding, please refer to this dbfiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/bCrXMfUS

Comment: Issue with constraint is when record being update with other column, Lets say user is Updating only Name , he is not updating date, then constrain will not prevent it. I do not want user to update value of any column which has older date.

Comment: And also, I am not able to enable constrain if table already has records with older date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `CURSOR` in a `TRIGGER`. A trigger should have as *minimal* impact on the calling statement as possible, and a `CURSOR` is one of the most **impactful** things you can have.

All you need to do here is use an `EXISTS` to check if the a row exists that you don't want and the `THROW` an error. Don't use `ROLLBACK` in a `TRIGGER` as thist give a meaningful error to the end user; have the outer query handle the rolling back of the transaction:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTrigger_ins ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted
               WHERE InvoiceDate < '20220101')
       THROW 50001, N'An error was thrown in the trigger ''dbo.YourTrigger_ins'' on the table ''dbo.YourTable''. A row where the invoice date is prior to 2022-01-01 cannot be inserted.', 16;
END;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTrigger_upd ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM deleted
               WHERE InvoiceDate < '20220101')
       THROW 50002, N'An error was thrown in the trigger ''dbo.YourTrigger_upd'' on the table ''dbo.YourTable''. A row where the invoice date is prior to 2022-01-01 cannot be updated.', 16;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM inserted
               WHERE InvoiceDate < '20220101')
       THROW 50003, N'An error was thrown in the trigger ''dbo.YourTrigger_upd'' on the table ''dbo.YourTable''. The value of the invoice date cannot be updated to be prior to 2022-01-01 .', 16;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HWMORfr9)

Comment: Lets say I am using Update statement with OR condition in where clause, and for those selected records, few records are with old date and rest are after 20220101, still it does not update any records. Is there any way to resolve this? Let say I use,   dbo.YourTable
SET InvoiceDate = '20221212'
WHERE ID = 2 or ID=1

Comment: The *entire* statement/batch will be aborted, @Teknas . So if you tried to `INSERT` 100 rows and just *one* had a "bad" value, none would be `INSERT`ed.

Comment: True. Hence I was trying with the cursor to resolve batch issue. Would it resolve it if we use cursor in your trigger?

Comment: No, you would need to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger like in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743741/2029983) from [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk), @Teknas  and silently discard the `UPDATE`d/`INSERT`ed rows and the end user would have **no idea** that their DML statement had been (partially) rejected. I am, personally, not a fan of that.

Comment: I tried with INSTEAD OF as shown by @nbk, you are right, it does not throw errors with even one invalid record insert. I am not sure about multiple/batch INSERT and UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

When you want to exclude inserts from actually being inserteed which a condition you can do it in a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger

```
create table tb(InvoiceNo int, InvoiceDate Date, CustomerName varchar(10));
```

```
insert into tb values(3,'2021-08-06','B');
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER IgnoreInvoices ON dbo.tb
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
 AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT dbo.tb(InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate,CustomerName)
        SELECT InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate,CustomerName
        FROM inserted
        WHERE InvoiceDate >= '2022-01-01';
    END
```

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER IgnoreInvoicesupdate ON dbo.tb
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
 AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF EXISTS 
  (
     SELECT 1 FROM inserted i
       JOIN deleted AS d ON i.InvoiceNo = d.InvoiceNo
       WHERE d.InvoiceDate >= '2022-01-01' AND i.InvoiceDate >= '2022-01-01'  
  )
  BEGIN
     UPDATE src 
       SET CustomerName = i.CustomerName, 
          InvoiceDate = i.InvoiceDate
       FROM dbo.tb AS src
       INNER JOIN inserted AS i
       ON i.InvoiceNo = src.InvoiceNo
       AND (src.InvoiceDate <> i.InvoiceDate or src.CustomerName = i.CustomerName);
  END
    END
```

```
insert into tb values(4,'2022-05-02','A');
insert into tb values(2,'2021-08-06','B');
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
select * from tb
```

| InvoiceNo | InvoiceDate | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-08-06 | B |
| 4 | 2022-05-02 | A |

```
UPDATE tb SET InvoiceDate = '2021-05-02' WHERE InvoiceNo = 4;;
UPDATE tb SET InvoiceDate = '2022-05-02' WHERE InvoiceNo = 3;;
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
select * from tb
```

| InvoiceNo | InvoiceDate | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-08-06 | B |
| 4 | 2022-05-02 | A |

```
Delete from TB
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
insert into tb values(1,'2021-08-06','B');
insert into tb values(2,'2022-05-02','A');---This record is correct but still it won't insert
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
select * from tb
```

| InvoiceNo | InvoiceDate | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-05-02 | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/USPWn1ua)

Comment: I works well with Insert, but it does not work with Update statement

Comment: usually you fill in the rest, as it is quite simple to deduce